# Like button doesn't work on my site

Tags: facebook-like

My website has a like button that doesn't publish anything on facebook.

http://www.abuze.com.br/cidade/7-florianopolis/oferta/2332-2-diarias-para-2-pessoas-na-pousada-timoteo-em-florianopolis-sc-com-33-de-desconto

What is going on?

PS: This like button has worked before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
 xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
```

on `<html>`

And test with facebook debugger tools :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abuze.com.br%2Fcidade%2F7-florianopolis%2Foferta%2F2332-2-diarias-para-2-pessoas-na-pousada-timoteo-em-florianopolis-sc-com-33-de-desconto

Comment: After check your page on facebook tools, your like button works !
However, you have lots js errors